# My horizontal scrollview is not working

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, containers

I've added a scrollview to a view in my app, the view is selected from a tab controller and as such is a container and not a UIViewController it is declared as below

```
class HomeViewController: Container, UIScrollViewDelegate {..
```

I've added the scrollview  in the storyboard and added all of the components to it and I've assigned the delegate from the storyboard and I've placed this code in my ViewController

```
scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width:1048, height:scrollview.frame.height)
scrollview.delegate = self
```

This how my ScrollView looks in my storyboard, you can see that scrollview is my UIScrollView, then I've added a UIView viewScroll and then added four views to viewScroll (View1, View2, View3 and View4), scrollview is sized at 375x340 and viewScroll is set at 1048x340

[image]

When I run the app it does not scroll. As it is not a UIViewController, do I need to approach this differently or is there something else I have missed?

Comment: Please show your code.. Especially when you are setting view size, etc

Comment: have you set the content size of scroll view. Also check that scrolling in enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've added the scrollview in the storyboard and set the width as 1050 and height as 330

You should set the width and height of scroll view to be at most as large as its containing view. What you need to set to 1050 and 330 is contentSize of the scroll view - scrollView is only scrollable when its contentSize is larger than its bounds.

If you're setting up your scroll view using Interface Builder, then you'll need to add constraints to its children's edges. For example, in your case you'll have to add leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints to your `View Scroll` view. Select it and add following constraints in interface builder:

[image: Constraints]

After that there will be something like this:

[image]

When you add edge constraints to `UIScrollView`s child views, you are hinting the scroll view about its content size. And if scroll view knows its content size and it is larger than scroll view's bounds, you'll have scroll working.

Comment: Thank you for your help Dan, I really appreciate it. I've set the scrollview in the storyboard to 375x325 and I've added this code to the viewcontroller viewDidLoad() scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1050, height: 325) but it still does not work. I'm missing something so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @user616076 please show us how do you add content to your scroll view.

Comment: I've amended my original post above, please let me know what you think

Comment: @user616076 did you set `View Scroll` edge constraints to `Scroll View`? For example, `leading` anchor of the former to same anchor of the latter?

Comment: No I didn't, could you please elaborate as That may well be what I'm missing

Comment: @user616076 I've updated my answer with explanation on how to do this.